# JPA how to design multiple tables one-to-one Relationship with a common table

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

I have a situation where few tables (TableA & TableB) have one-to-one relationship with a same table  (TableC). TableA and TableB are unrelated. I have designed the tables as below.

```
TableA
- key
- something
- c_ref_key

TableB
- key
- something
- c_ref_key

TableC
- key
- something
```

When I generate JPA entity from this database using hibernate reverse-engineering, it create many-to-one relation in TableA and TableB for TableC. Normally to create one-to-one relationship I would have TableA primary key as primary key of TableC but since I have other tables (TableB) which also have one-to-one relationship with TableC , I cant do that. Hence I had to use TableC's foreign key in TableA and TableB (which resulted in many-to-one relationship in JPA). 
Is there any other way to design to keep the relationships one-to-one ? or atleast in generated JPA entities can have one-to-one relationship ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use @OneToOne hibernate mapping with @JoinColumn to create foreign key. Below is the very basic implementation for schema, You can extend it as per your requirements.

TableA.java

```
    @Entity(name = "TABLE_A")
    public class TableA {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long key_a;

        private String something;

        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "c_ref_key", referencedColumnName = "key_c")
        private TableC c_ref_key;
    }
```

TableB.java

```
@Entity(name = "TABLE_B")
public class TableB {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long key_b;

    private String something;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "c_ref_key", referencedColumnName = "key_c")
    private TableC c_ref_key;
}
```

TableC.java

```
@Entity(name = "TABLE_C")
public class TableC {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long key_c;

    private String something;
}
```

I tested this schema on MySql database and It works fine.

Comment: Thanks pbajpai21 for the reply. Our JPA entites are auto generated. We are using hibernate ant task to reverse engineer the JPA entities from database. However your answer has provided the hint. I will use the `hibernate.reveng.xml` to control the reverse engineering strategy and use it to force one-to-one relation on the foreign key. Appreciate your help.